# dropzonejs send for every photo one ajax

Tags: php, ajax, file, upload, dropzone.js

I want send multiple file with **dropzone.js** to the server when my form submitted.
**HTML** and **js**

```
<form id="hotelDetails-entry" method="post" action="server/php/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone dz-clickable"></div>
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="save"/>
</form>

<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#hotel_name,#hotelNum').on('blur',function () {
        var villaNum = $('#hotelNum').val().length;
        var villaName = $('#hotel_name').val().length;
        $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
        if((villaNum > 4) && (villaName > 0)){
            $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    });

    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        url: "server/php/",
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictRemoveFile: 'حذف',
        dictDefaultMessage: 'کلیک کنید',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        parallelUploads : 10,
        sending: function (file,xhr,formData) {

        },
        init: function () {
            myDropzone = this;
            $('#hotelDetails-entry').on("submit", function() {
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
        },
        success: function (file,res) {

        },
        error: function (file,error,c) {
            $('.error').html(error);
        }
    };
});
```

**php**

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {

global $Core;
global $mysqli;
$upload = Upload::factory('image/hotel',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/hotel/");//   upload herer
$upload->file($_FILES['file']);
//set max. file size (in mb)
$upload->set_max_file_size(1);

//set allowed mime types
$upload->set_allowed_mime_types(array('image/jpeg'));

$results = $upload->upload();

if($results['status'] == true){



        $inserHotel = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `hotels` (`hotelNum`, `hotel_name`, .....
        $vilId = mysqli_insert_id($inserHotel);
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `gallery` (`hotel_id`, `img`, `des`) VALUES ('". $vilId ."', '', NULL)");

    }


}
```

When every photo inserted into table one row.because for every photo send one ajax request.How to send all of photos in one request to the server.I want save name of upload photo that response from Upload.php to database depend on hotel_id

Comment: @Asif Rao thanks for edit

Answer (score 0):

i find it
just 
`Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            url: "testFile.php",
            paramName: "files", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 2, // MB
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            dictRemoveFile: 'حذف',
            dictDefaultMessage: 'کلیک کنید',
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            parallelUploads : 10,
            uploadMultiple: true,<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this is problem
            sending: function (file,xhr,formData) {`